# Pixelation on my UV image text

Tags: shaders

I've added my UV texture, and I can see white pixelated borders around my red text. What's causing this?
also below are the nodes I'm using, The text is supposedly going onto a screen surface. which isn't so realistic, any ideas what other nodes I can use to give it some screen surface feeling? I've seen some internet suggestions which are overkill over 10 nodes to get what's meant to be a realistic glass reflection. But I'd like a bit more minimal node composition if it's possible to get a nice result.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's cause by your reference image, which is an png image I guess?

PNG(Portable Network Graphic) is not just a simple algorithm but an image storage solutions bucket. There are two main way to implement the thing "**Transparency**". And you might choose the simpler one:

[image]

If I use PNG-8 bit(paletted method) I will got the strange White border. That is actually coming from matte color since paletted method only allow one transparency value instead an alpha channel. When I choose PNG-24 bit(true color with alpha) we get a better image without border.
[image]

So you need to redo that image to make the border show as an actual color. Or you can also use your image as **alpha material socket** input to reduce the white border effect.

Comment: Ah... my image is made from Photoshop if you want to know. I am pretty sure **GIMP** got the same option to deal with saving PNG.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried PNG 24, and still getting the same result.

Comment: Found a great solution, in the node editor:

Change from Linear to Closest in your Image-Node, and it works perfect.

Comment: @blenderbreath great idea, Blender use interpolation between those non-opaque color (which should be white as default?), you might want to upscale your png file if you want a smooth edge and no white border. Also you can answer your own question, that is a good practice

Answer (score 1):

Found a great solution, in the node editor: Change from Linear to Closest in your Image-Node, and it works perfect.